# How do I import the bootstrap.min.js into Vue JS

Tags: vue.js

My Vue JS app Bootstrap nav-bar does not work in mobile. I have installed the Bootstrap, JQuery and popper node modules. My Vue JS app displays the error ***Module Not Found. Can't resolve 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap'***

Here is my code on my App.vue

```
<style lang="scss">
$primary: #05b2dd;
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
</style>

<script>
import "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min";
import "node_modules/popper/dist/popper.min";
import "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min";
</script>
```

The file path in my Vue app is present: node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 0):

I've moved the import of the JS files to main.js. Here is the code snippet

```
import "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min";
import "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min";
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap";
```

The navigation is now working on mobile